# Facebook app doesn't pop up for permissions

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

Everything works fine with test users but when I publish my app and user clicks on app the permission popup dialog box does not appear. I guess there is some oauth problem but not sure. Please help me out

```
require 'facebook-files/facebook.php';
$app_id='xxxxxxxxxx';
$secret='xxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' => $secret,
  'cookie'=> true,
  'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
));

// Get User ID
 $user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
      //$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends?fields=id,name,birthday,picture');
        $event = $facebook->api('/me/?fields=events.fields(id,name)');

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

    echo "Exception".error_log($e);
    $user = null;
    exit;
  }
}
// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
  'scope'  => 'read_stream,publish_actions,publish_stream,user_birthday,friends_birthday', 'display'=>'popup')
  );
}
```

Comment: Just making sure... But your pop up blocker is disabled right? If you have a pop up blocker enabled it will block the permissions window.

Comment: I do not have any pop up blocker for sure

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add your site to the "valid oauth redirect uris" input field in your app's settings.